# How to run a property's set without changing its value?

Tags: c#, properties

I am trying to use a property to enable or disable a button whenever the property's value is changed.

For example:

```
string test
        {
            get
            {
                return xmlValue; // Reads a value from an XML file
            }
            set
            {
                if (xmlValue == null)
                {
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }

                xmlValue = value; // Writes the value to an XML file
            }
        }
```

Now this works fine, except on startup. The button would always be enabled until `set` was called.

I tried this:

```
test = test;
```

And it seems to work OK. But is this the right way to do it?

Comment: to be  consistent, move the logic after your state has mutated. do `xmlValue = value` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would do the mutation first:

```
xmlValue = value; // Writes the value to an XML file

if (xmlValue == null)
{
   button1.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
   button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Regardless, I would do one of the following to initialize the state:

1. In the constructor, write `test = null` Even though its already in that state, at least you are explicitly initializing it as opposed to assigning it to itself.
2. Just set `button1.Enabled` to false in the designer/XAML. The initial property values should reflect the correct initial state of the program.

The assignment you posted will work, but doesn't read well, or make idiomatic sense, so I would avoid it.